# My code does not work with forEach method

Tags: javascript

I want to know why forEach would not work on this array but map does work.

I tried to use .map and it works but shouldn't forEach work as well

```
function letters() {
  let string = "abcd";

  let newString = string.split("").forEach(i => {
    return String.fromCharCode(i.charCodeAt(0) + 1);
  });

newString = newString.join("");

}
```

I get undefined when I use forEach

Comment: `forEach` and `map` do different things, they aren't interchangeable

Answer (score 1):

> shouldn't forEach work as well

No, it shouldn't. The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Return_value) says:

> **Return value**
>   `undefined`

This is the difference between `map` and `forEach`. They both call the function for each element of the array. `map` returns a new array containing the results, `forEach` ignores the results and doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `forEach`:

```
function letters() {
  let string = "abcd";

  let newString = '';
  string.split("").forEach(i => {
    newString += String.fromCharCode(i.charCodeAt(0) + 1);
  });

  return newString;

}
```